# How to get user verification status (Blue badge) while logging in with Facebook SDK V4 or V5 in angular 8?

Tags: angular, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want the get the user verification information, e.g. user have blue badge on his/her account or not. I searched the Graph Api reference but nothing helpful found.
I already tried "is_verified", "verified", "verification_status".

```
let permissions = ["email", "public_profile"];
 this.fb.api("/me?fields=name,email,is_verified", permissions)
     .then(user => {
       console.log("user log", user);
     })
```

Comment: Do user profiles even get these? Pretty sure that is a thing for pages only.

Comment: User profiles can get blue badge. You can check the profile of any famous celebrity.

Comment: Those _are_ usually pages, not user profiles.

Answer (score 0):

According to the API reference, the correct field is `verification_status`. I just did a test with some random Page and it worked perfectly fine:

```
{
  "verification_status": "blue_verified",
  "id": "xxx"
}
```

API: `/page-id?fields=verification_status` (with an App Access Token)

**Be aware that this is only available for Pages, NOT user profiles.** Also, you need to apply for [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS) in order to get the data of Pages you do not manage. For you own Pages, you can just use a Page Access Token with `/me?fields=verification_status`.

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/

Comment: Thank you. I think verification status was available for user profiles as well in previous SDKs. It is marked as deprecated in newer SDK. Is there any other possible way to check blue badge for user profiles?

Comment: not that i know of, and if it is marked as deprecated without any info about a new possibility...